# My front tire sidewall is damaged

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

My tire sidewall is damaged as shown in this picture. I'm not sure when and how that happened. There is no air leak or any shaking.
But I want to make sure is it still safe to drive. I have driven more than 500 miles with it. Do I have to replace or repair on my own? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

More pictures necessary, but if, when you lift up the rubber, you can see the plies then you have to replace it.

If that is a deep cut then the plies may have been weakened anyway and you should replace it for your safety and that of others as there will be no telling when it could fail ie at 70mph is a corner on a mountain road...